# VSCode auto import incorrect path

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I start Angular 5 project in vscode, however auto import is not work as expect, is there any work around ?

instead of import this

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms/src/form_providers';
```

can it be change to this

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
```

Here is my list of extension...

[image]

[image]

Here is how the suggestion show.., I have try all options

[image]

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "dating-app.spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.6.1"
  }
}
```

## EDIT 1

Now it's working, didn't do anythings from op above, just leave and try again (without restart computer) this morning.

VSCode - Version 1.22.2 (1.22.2)

Node.JS - v9.11.1

Angular CLI - v1.7.4

TypeScript - v2.6.1 (using local version in project, you can switch version)

## EDIT 2

After restart, it's not working anymore. And it's import the incorrect one.

Comment: updating VsCode may help

Comment: I just update, today

Comment: I don't know why, today it's now working, didn't do anythings from op question.